# Angular CLI: creating service Error: classify is not defined after npm install

Tags: node.js, angular

Hi i have very strange problem, before run comand

> sudo npm install

in angular 5 project, i can creating modules, components, and services via ng.
After:

> sudo npm install

When i want to create for example service:

> sudo ng generate service myName

I get error:

> Error: classify is not defined, classify is not defined

Version node: **9.5.0**
Version npm: **5.6.0**
Angular CLI: **1.7.1**
Angular: **5.2.6**

My package.json:

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.42",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.23",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.96",
    "codelyzer": "^4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.9.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just ran into this issue, and updating Angular DevKit worked for me:

```
$ npm i -D @angular-devkit/core@latest
```

Comment: For @angular/cli: "1.7.2"  => @angular-devkit/core: "0.4.3" works